# Why does Unity say "Compenent,Get,component(type) is a method, which is not valid in the given context"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't understand what is wrong with that line.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SendInfo : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () { }

    void Update () {
      bool RMB = Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1);

      if (RMB) {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.transform.tag == "Ground"){
            // error on the next line
            this.GetComponent<Photonview>()
                .RPC("RecievedMove", PhotonTargets.All, hit.point);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code. It is likely error you see is due to some other code (i.e. methods outside a class) - please make sure the code is enough to reproduce the problem. Also post exact error message as part of the body of  the post. ([edit] post, don't post code as comments)

Comment: is this better Alexei

Comment: which line are you having problems with ?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I don't see it lol

Comment: @Clint "//error on the next line" shows where the problem with the code is

Comment: is this a compile time error, can you give more specifics about the error ?

Comment: Anyway you shouldn't use `GetComponent` repeatedly at all .. rather store the reference **once** in `Start` or even already by drag&drop in the Inspector in a serialized (`public` or `[SerializeField] private`) field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that PhotonView is written differently so:

```
this.GetComponent<Photonview>().RPC("RecievedMove", PhotonTargets.All, hit.point);
```

should be

```
this.GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC("RecievedMove", PhotonTargets.All, hit.point);
```